# Is that possible I can use the CFRunloop mechanism within a threadFunction created by pthread?

Tags: pthreads, nsthread, nsrunloop, cfrunloop

For some reason, I cannot use NSThread. But I thing the communication way using the CFRunloopSource between 2 threads is convient. So I wonder that if I can obtain the current cfrunloop ref within the thread context created by pthread?

I grabbed online and indeed saw some comments that even using pthread the runloop ref was still available. But I didn't see anything about this from the documentation. So I would like to ask someone here who has the related experience.

Furthermore, can I share the CFRunloopRef retrieved from the new thread by:
CFRetain(CFRunLoopGetCurrent()) between the new thread and my current thread?
Because the ref is needed when I want to trigger the runloop in the newly-created thread
by
CFRunLoopWakeUp(ref)

Thanks,

Jack Seraph